# errno 2 no such file or directory from command line file in python

Tags: python

I am getting that error for my program with my sys.argv[1] file.  The specific csv file i am importing is there i can see it and open it myself.

```
myfile = open("sys.argv[1]", "r")
reader = csv.DictReader(myfile)
dnalist = list()
for dictionary in reader:
    dnalist.appeand(dictionary)
```

It cant seem to find the file I input into my command line.  I double checked that I am in the correct folder and spell the name of the subfolder correctly and the file name.

Comment: Don't put `sys.argv[1]` in quotes. That makes it use that literal string as the filename, it doesn't evaluate the variable.

Comment: You have a typo: `appeand` should be `append`

Comment: You can replace the entire loop with `dnalist = list(reader)`

Comment: Thank you.  Only started python this week!

Comment: Where in your tutorials did you get the idea that you needed to put variables inside quotes?